# Drop Down contents width is wider and out of screen

Tags: html, css

HI I have the following html and this is part of the html.

```
<div class="pad1x flex-row leftLblMode">
    <div class="pad1x flex-col-xs-12 flex-col-sm-6">
        <div style="">
            <label for="kaf_16" id="klb_16" class="input-control-label">
                Code
                <span class="mandatory">*</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pad1x flex-col-xs-12 flex-col-sm-6">
        <select name="kaf_16" id="kaf_16" aria-label="kaf_16" aria-required="true" data-sid="ddl_code" class="input-control" data-klookup="C_1" data-kcurrentval="" style="font-weight: bold;">
            <option value="+01">+01</option>
            <option value="+02">+02</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

When clicked on drop down, the contents is showing out of the screen and I am viewing the contents in mobile view in the browser.

[image]

I tried the css as below but it is not working.

```
.tabularView .input-control{
position: relative;
}
```

I am trying to find the solution and learn in the process.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: To understand your problem you should ask for complete code, pls post CSS with all code, in that case, a better solution can be given.